# Javascript/HTML Elements Error

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a bit of trouble with this code:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT">
<!--
    var checkCookie = ""
    checkCookie = getCookie("StudentName")
    alert("The value of checkCookie is " + checkCookie)
    if (checkCookie != null) {
    location = "frames.htm"
    }

    function addCookie(tag, value) {
        var expireDate = new Date()
        var expireString = ""
        expireDate.setTime(expireDate.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365))
        expireString = "expires=" + expireDate.toGMTString()
        document.cookie = tag + "=" + escape(value) + ";" + expireString + ";"
    }

    function updateValues() {
        if (document.StudentInformation.StudentName.value != null &&
            document.StudentInformation.StudentName.value != "")
            addCookie("StudentName", document.StudentInformation.StudentName.value)
    }
    var numElements = document.StudentInformation.elements.length

    for (var i=1; i<numElements - 2; i++) {
        if (document.StudentInformation.elements[i].value != null &&
            document.StudentInformation.elements[i].value != "")
            addCookie(document.StudentInformation.elements[i].name,
            document.StudentInformation.elements[i].checked)

    }


    function getCookie(tag) {
        var value = null
        var myCookie = document.cookie + ";"
        var findTag= tag + "="
        var endPos

        if (myCookie.length > 0) {
        var beginPos = myCookie.indexOf(findTag)
        if (beginPos != -1) {
            beginPos = beginPos + findTag.length
            endPos = myCookie.indexOf(";",beginPos)
            if (endPos == -1)
                endPos = myCookie.length
            value = unescape(myCookie.substring(beginPos,endPos))
            }
        }
        return value
    }

    function deleteCookies() {
        var Yesterday = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        var expireDate = new Date()

        expireDate.setTime (expireDate.getTime() - Yesterday)
        document.cookie = "StudentName=nothing; expires=" + expireDate.toGMTString()
        document.StudentInformation.StudentName.value = ""
    }
//-->
</SCRIPT>
```

More importantly, my debugger gives me "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined", referencing this:

this line specifically---->

```
var numElements = document.StudentInformation.elements.length

    for (var i=1; i<numElements - 2; i++) {
        if (document.StudentInformation.elements[i].value != null &&
            document.StudentInformation.elements[i].value != "")
            addCookie(document.StudentInformation.elements[i].name,
            document.StudentInformation.elements[i].checked)

    }
```

If anyone could help me, that'd be wonderful :)
Here's the full page, if you need it:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Student Council Preferences</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JAVASCRIPT">
<!--
    var checkCookie = ""
    checkCookie = getCookie("StudentName")
    alert("The value of checkCookie is " + checkCookie)
    if (checkCookie != null) {
    location = "frames.htm"
    }

    function addCookie(tag, value) {
        var expireDate = new Date()
        var expireString = ""
        expireDate.setTime(expireDate.getTime() + (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365))
        expireString = "expires=" + expireDate.toGMTString()
        document.cookie = tag + "=" + escape(value) + ";" + expireString + ";"
    }

    function updateValues() {
        if (document.StudentInformation.StudentName.value != null &&
            document.StudentInformation.StudentName.value != "")
            addCookie("StudentName", document.StudentInformation.StudentName.value)
    }
    var numElements = document.StudentInformation.elements.length

    for (var i=1; i<numElements - 2; i++) {
        if (document.StudentInformation.elements[i].value != null &&
            document.StudentInformation.elements[i].value != "")
            addCookie(document.StudentInformation.elements[i].name,
            document.StudentInformation.elements[i].checked)

    }


    function getCookie(tag) {
        var value = null
        var myCookie = document.cookie + ";"
        var findTag= tag + "="
        var endPos

        if (myCookie.length > 0) {
        var beginPos = myCookie.indexOf(findTag)
        if (beginPos != -1) {
            beginPos = beginPos + findTag.length
            endPos = myCookie.indexOf(";",beginPos)
            if (endPos == -1)
                endPos = myCookie.length
            value = unescape(myCookie.substring(beginPos,endPos))
            }
        }
        return value
    }

    function deleteCookies() {
        var Yesterday = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
        var expireDate = new Date()

        expireDate.setTime (expireDate.getTime() - Yesterday)
        document.cookie = "StudentName=nothing; expires=" + expireDate.toGMTString()
        document.StudentInformation.StudentName.value = ""
    }
//-->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFCC" TEXT="#00384A">
  <CENTER>
    <img src="header1.gif" width="472" height="108"> 
    <p>
    <img src="please.gif" width="472" height="55"></p>
  </CENTER>

  <FORM NAME="StudentInformation" onSubmit="return updateValues()" onReset="return deleteCookies()">
  <CENTER>
    <TABLE BORDER=0>
        <TR>
            <TD>Name: </TD>
            <TD><INPUT TYPE="text" SIZE=20 NAME="StudentName"></TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE>
    <BR>

    <TABLE BORDER=0 CELLPADDING=2>
        <TR>
            <TD>Alumni Association</TD>
            <TD><input type="checkbox" name="interest1"></TD>
            <TD WIDTH=50></TD>
            <TD>Astronomy Club</TD>
            <TD><input type="checkbox" name="interest2"></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>Student Government</TD>
            <TD><input type="checkbox" name="interest3"></TD>
            <TD WIDTH=50></TD>
            <TD>Radio and Television Club</TD>
            <TD><input type="checkbox" name="interest4"></TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
            <TD>Intramural Sports</TD>
            <TD><input type="checkbox" name="interest5"></TD>
            <TD WIDTH=50></TD>
            <TD>Scuba Club</TD>
            <TD><input type="checkbox" name="interest6"></TD>
        </TR>
    </TABLE> 
    <BR>
    <INPUT TYPE="submit" NAME="Continue" VALUE="Continue">
    <INPUT TYPE="reset" NAME="Reset" VALUE="Clear All">
  </CENTER>
  </FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: post the document. there seams to be no object "StudentInformation"

Comment: Please provide more information or edit this question to be more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, I believe, is that the block of code you pointed to is executing as soon as the browser interprets it. Since it is inline Javascript located earlier in the document than your form (named StudentInformation) is, when it is executed StudentInformation doesn't exist yet!

A common pattern for dealing with this is to wait until the whole page is loaded before manipulating or querying any page elements. For example:

```
window.onload = function() {
  var numElements = document.StudentInformation.elements.length

  for (var i=1; i<numElements - 2; i++) {
    if (document.StudentInformation.elements[i].value != null &&
        document.StudentInformation.elements[i].value != "")
        addCookie(document.StudentInformation.elements[i].name,
        document.StudentInformation.elements[i].checked)

  }
};
```